# how to set only specific types to the interface

Tags: typescript

`address` is a map. it has so many `keys` in the database. I didn't want to pass all `keys` to my other API.

```
export interface BookingModel {
    address: Address
}
```

I want to pass only these three types to API

```
export interface Address {
    location: string,
    flatNo: string,
    id: string
}
```

I pass address details like this.

```
{
    'addressDetails': bookingModel.address,
}
```

**But `addressDetails` has all keys, not specified keys.**

Comment: how about using `Pick` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a `pick` function to prune your full-fat address down in a typesafe fashion:

```
const pick = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> => {
  const keySet = new Set(keys);
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(
    ([k]) => keySet.has(k as K))) as Pick<T, K>;
}
```

then use it:

```
{
    addressDetails: pick(bookingModel.address, 'location', 'flatNo', 'id'),
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think better `null` check. Otherwise getting error right?  `if(!obj) return obj;`